# Docker daemon not starting

Tags: docker

I am finding issues when starting docker daemon.

```
sudo dockerd
```

Getting following error

> chmod /var/lib/docker: read-only file system

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and docker version is 18.06.3-ce. The docker was running properly earlier but somehow `/var/lib/docker` went in read-only state. So I killed docker process but now it's not starting again.

`sudo mount` does not list `/var/lib/docker` however `/proc/mounts` does contain following line

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/id /var/lib/docker ext4
>   ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0

I asked on slack channel and forum but didn't get any response. Please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: not sure why it doesn't happen to anyone else. Do you use a virtual environment ?

Comment: What is your platform (Operating System, version, etc) and how did you install Docker?

Comment: Updated with some info.

Comment: The OS may put the file system into read only due to some troubles. Please investigate the hard disk/partition issues first.

Comment: Did you follow the steps from docker to install it? https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/